# os.isdir not working on Mac after create executeable with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

i try to check the existing files and folders using the following code:

```
import os, sys
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
listFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(path)] 
existDirs = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(x)]

print(path)
print(listFiles)
print(existDirs)
```

I also create executeables for this file using:

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

On Windows everything works find (the output is correct when i directly run the test.py and also when i run the created executeable).

But on Mac when i run the pyhon file test.py everything works fine and the output looks like this:

```
/Users/polzimac/Documents/DEV/Fiverr/ORDER/robalf/gptFiles
['chatGPT.spec', '.DS_Store', 'dist', 'CHUNK 1', 'test.py', 'test.spec', 'chatGPT.py', 'chatGPT', 'build']
['dist', 'CHUNK 1', 'build']
```

But when i run the created program on Mac i get this output and the existDir-output is empty:

```
/Users/polzimac/Documents/DEV/Fiverr/ORDER/robalf/gptFiles
['chatGPT.spec', '.DS_Store', 'test', 'dist', 'CHUNK 1', 'test.py', 'test.spec', 'chatGPT.py', 'chatGPT', 'build']
[]
```

Why is existDirs empty when i run the compiled program on Mac?

Comment: Add `print(os. getcwd())` to `test.py`, rebuild, rerun, and post result.

Comment: the output for this is: /Users/polzimac
(when i run the py-file its /Users/polzimac/Documents/DEV/Fiverr/ORDER/robalf/gptFiles but when i run the compiled exe-file its only /Users/polzimac)

Comment: That is why you have different behaviour. Add details about in which directory you build and how you run the compiled exe-file.

Comment: Hello - i allways built the executeable in the same folder as the py-file (the path you see in the print(path) statement with the command `pyinstaller --onefile test.py`

Comment: I run it from the same directoy as the py-file

Comment: But i think i found now the solution - with that statement it is also working when i run the executeable on MacOs: `existDirs2= [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, x))]`

Comment: If you want you can write an answer for that and i will approve it as solution.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you currect directory is `/Users/polzimac` indicates that you ran the compiled exe-file from `/Users/polzimac`. The solutkion is to test directory with a parent directory:

```
existDirs2= [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, x))]
```